# Java HttpServlet sending gson string, JavaScript getting it as array

Tags: jquery, json, servlets, jqgrid

Server side I have this Java:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

    resp.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");        
    resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    Extent<Video> extent = pm.getExtent(Video.class, false);

    ArrayList<Video> list = new ArrayList<Video>(); 
    for (Video e : extent) {
        list.add(e);
    }

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(list);
    System.out.println(json); // As expected: [{"id":34,"title":"a title","videoUrl":"an.mp4","imageUrl":"a.jpg" etc.
    resp.getWriter().write(json);

    extent.closeAll();
    pm.close();

}
```

Client side I have this JavaScript using jQuery:

```
var getAllRequest = $.ajax({ 
 url: "http://localhost:8888/getAll",
 type: "GET",
 dataType: "json"
});
getAllRequest.done(function(response) {         
 alert (response) // THIS IS AN OBJECT ARRAY, i.e., [object Object],[object Object] etc. 
});
```

**My question**: is response really a json object, or just an array of json objects.
I'm using jq grid, and it does not fill in the grid when given the response. (Feeding the response to the jq grid not shown here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON gives you the way to post information about the object as string. So there are no "json object". Either you have string with for example the text like

```
var str = '[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]]';
```

or you have an object for example

```
var myObj = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]];
```

The full specification of JSON is described [here](http://www.json.org/) or in [rfc4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt). So you should not mix the initialization syntax which allows you to create object with the JSON string with very close syntax.

If you use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with `dataType: "json"` parameter and the server response contains JSON string jqGrid internally convert the server response to object (see [$.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) function) and the parameter of the `done` will be already object. So you could use

```
alert(response.length);
```

for example inside of callback function of `getAllRequest.done`. In any way the client seems to get correctly the server response.

Comment: The strange thing to me is that the java side print statement indicates that what is being sent is a string, but the client side gets an object array, not a string.

Comment: @normc: Please reread my answer. The server must send string. The client side (the `$.ajax`) just convert the string to object for you. If you need to see the response as the string you can use `complete` callback of `$.ajax` for example.